# Java Script JSON built in var not defined

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to use JSON.parse() in java script but it says json is not defined.
Why does my browser transform JSON into json ? How can I fix it ?
Note : I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>` just before.
Here's my code :

```js
$.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
     });
      const queryString = window.location.search;
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      if (urlParams.has("target")) {
        console.log("Redirecting ...");
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);  // says json is not defined
        eval("window.location.replace(obj." + urlParams.get("target") + ");")
      } else {
        console.log("Missing target argument, printing error ...");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Missing target argument !";
      }
```

And the error : `"Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined at line 7"`.
Thank you !

Comment: You're ending the callback function on the third line...   The `json` variable is scoped to that callback.

Comment: I didn't know, thanks ! I'm trying to fix it now

Comment: But Firefox underline "JSON", not the "json" var

Comment: `JSON` is fine.

Comment: Does it say `JSON is undefined` or `json is undefined`? The error should be about `json`.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`?

Comment: the error is about json

Comment: You don't need eval, just: `window.location.replace(obj[urlParams.get("target")]);`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property

Comment: I use eval because I want to get the info of the obj var, specified in url

Comment: Oh, thank you, I forgot to test that

Comment: Oh, and FYI:  "JavaScript" is one word, not two.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amy and Barmar, the problem was just that json was from outer scope, so I put all my code in the json function and it works great ! Thanks